# Can we run programs simultaneously in both the operating system of a single CPU?

Tags: windows, linux, compatibility

I have a system with two operating systems - Windows 7 and Ubuntu. Now I want to run a program in both Ubuntu and Windows.

To explain better, I want to run the Windows program while I am working in Ubuntu. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot normally run two operating systems at the same time, because both want to take over all the hardware.

There are basically two options:

1. use virtualization to run one operating system inside the other
2. run the "foreign" application using some kind of compatibility layer, such as Cygwin (for running Linux apps on Windows) or Wine (for running Windows apps on Linux)

Comment: Virtualbox of oracle can be used to run any OS in any oS.

Comment: @tarakaramji: Yes, that's why I mentioned virtualization.